# Copy to clipboard using commonsware cwac-richedit library

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm currently trying to use the https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit library which work when it's come to Formatting. 
However, I'm currently trying to copy text out of the richedittext seems to not work. As a feedback from the clipboard, I do receive a Toast message saying "Already Exists".

The LogCat give me an error as well "ClipboardServiceEx Fail set data".

I'm using the library on android 4.2 and without the Actionbar sherlock.

Any Idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: How specifically are you "trying to copy text out of the richedittext "? Please post some code.

Comment: I'm trying to copy using the tablet by using long press, selecting the text and try to paste it either in another application or editText.

Comment: I can provide you code, however, i'm not doing anything special. I just display the richEditText in the layout and for the code just using the enableActionModes(true) function.

Comment: Oh, you mean you are doing this as a user. I thought that you meant that you were doing it as a developer, working with `ClipboardManager` and stuff. Is this reproducible in the demo project?

Comment: Yes, I just managed to reproduce this problem by running the demo project on my tablet (Galaxy Note 10.1). Same Toast message and same logCat error.

Comment: OK, I'll take a peek at this, though it may not be for a day or two.

Comment: thanks, let me know if you find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not get the `Toast` that you describe in a 4.2 emulator, I can reproduce the problem with copying text -- nothing seems to make it to the clipboard.

I have filed [an issue to track this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit/issues/5), though my plate is a bit full right now, so it will be some time before I will be able to work to resolve this. That will be as part of an overall revamp of this library, which is old and dusty.

Comment: BTW, this is fixed in v0.3.0 of the library.